# C - undeclared first use

Tags: c

When I execute the following C code snippet, I receive the following error:

"box.c:2:23: error: ‘fblog’ undeclared (first use in this function)
box.c:2:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in"

I have to confess to having very little experience with C, but I am hoping that someone will spot the problem.

I have tried to define fblog as unsigned short but that just threw another error ?!

```
void putpixel(int x, int y, unsigned short color) {
    unsigned short *fblog;
    unsigned short *fb = fblog;
    *(fb + (y * 240) + x) = color; 
}

void drawbox(void) {
    int x, y;
    for (x = 40; x <= 200; x++) {
        putpixel(x, 30, 0xF800);
        putpixel(x, 290, 0x001F);
    }
    for (y = 30; y <= 290; y++) {
        putpixel(40, y, 0x7E0);
        putpixel(200, y, 0x07E0);
    }
}

void main(){
    drawbox();
}
```

Comment: If you formatted your code, that would make significantly easier to debug it.

Comment: What is 'fblog'? From this snippet alone, it isn't declared at all (hence the error message). Either pass it as parameter, or declare it as global variable.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that fblog is undeclared, and its first use is on box.c line 2 (character 23).

Answer (score 2):

`fblog` is undeclared inside `putpixel` function. Try to declare it globally (which is bad in general) or pass it as a parameter.

> I have tried to define fblog as unsigned short but that just threw another error ?!

That's because `fb` is a **pointer** to `unsigned short`, not a `unsigned short` value, so you have declare `fblog` as `unsigned short *`, or initialize `fb` with the address of `fblog`. It depends on what you want to get.

Comment: Thanks, I declared fblog as unsigned short *, it compiled without error, but when I executed it I got a segmentation fault. This code is intended to draw a rectangle to the framebuffer under linux, but unfortunately it does not seem to work.

Comment: Was `fblog` properly initialized before the first use? Did it contain a valid address? Please add the declaration to your first post.

Comment: @crankshaft That's because it's a pointer, which points into nothingness. You need to assign it to an actual variable (for example `unsigned short var, *fblog = &var;` for it to work.

Comment: @crankshaft, your `fblog` inside `putpixel` is uninitialized and holds an arbitrary memory address, that's why you get a segfault. I don't really know how to use the framebuffer, but I think you have to map `fblog` to a specific memory address before the first use.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but I am giving up, all I want to do is to draw a box so I can debug screen settings, I honestly know nothing about C and copied this code snippet from a Philips NXP white paper expecting it to work right out of the box.